# how to display an image from database?

Tags: asp.net

i know too that this (kind of) question has been asked and answered many times. I myself have asked this once before. But I havnt been successful yet. how do I display the image in an image control for a particular employee ID... Heres my code:

`
        bind()
        GridView1.Visible = "True"

```
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT Image FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID =@EmployeeID"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value() = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("ImageID"))
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        **Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(1)("Image"), Byte())**
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows(1)("Name").ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End If`
```

Getting error at the line in bold. "There is no row at position 1"...
Actually I want to fetch (display) the image for a particular employee id. How does it concern a row position? I dont know why i have written that line of code. Anyway, I know there are guys who can help me with this and so I thank them in advance...

OK, Heres my code for adding the image to the database. This is working fine.

```
 Dim imageData As Byte() = New Byte(FileUpload1.FileContent.Length) {}
    FileUpload1.FileContent.Read(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload1.FileContent.Length))

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString").ToString)
    con.Open()
    If EmployeeIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter EmployeeID to Add Photo")
    Else
        Dim com As New SqlCommand("UPDATE EmployeeTable SET IMAGE = @IM where EmployeeID='" & EmployeeIDTextBox.Text & "'", con)
        Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName)
        'Dim imageData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IM", imageData)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("File Saved Successfully!")
    End If
End Sub
```

And now this is my code for retrieving & displaying the same image in an image control...

```
  bind()
    GridView1.Visible = "True"
    'If Request.QueryString("ImageID") IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT Image FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID =@EmployeeID"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value() = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("Image"))
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows(1)("Name").ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End IF
```

This is not working...

Comment: do u want to display in image control? and ur query returns image column from db and you are using `dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString)`. Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start from 0

Use

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Image"), Byte())
```

How is it that you don't know why you have written that?

The code you have will prompt a user to save the image file on his pc.
It will not show the image in an image control.

Comment: it was initially 0 only.. i was getting the same error... so i tried changing it....

Comment: also, i know its gonna throw a lot of other errors in the subsequent lines of code when i resolve this one...

Comment: If the error says `There is no row at position 1`, it is obvious that you were using the index 1 somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

U can use a Http Handler and use the below code in `ProcessRequest()`

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImgId"]);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(
"SELECT ImageFile FROM ImageTable WHERE ImageId = @ImgId", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@ImgId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id ;
conn.Open();
Response.ContentType = "image/gif"; //u can set it per ur requirement
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[]) command.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

and then use image in your page as :

```
  <asp:Image id="Img_Db" runat="server" ImageUrl="Image.ashx?ImgId=1"/>
```